# Application routing overrides modules routing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've met some interesting situation while developing application using `Angular 4.1.1`. I've always declared routing in a module and I do it in **all modules**.

For example, `new-cars.routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NewCarsComponent} from './new-cars.component';
import { NewCarsResolver } from './new-cars.resolver';    

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: 'cars/:id',
                component: NewCarsComponent,
                resolve: {
                    card: NewCarsResolver
                }
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class NewCarsRoutingModule { }
```

Then I've read this [article](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) to redirect to "404 Not Found" component, if user inputs not exisiting URL address. And I declared this route in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

and now all pages show `Page not found`.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import ...;
import { NewCarsModule } from './new-cars/new-cars.module';    
import ...;    

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HomeModule,
        SearchModule,
        CoreModule,            
        NewsCarsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, 
        PageNotFoundComponent
        ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My questions is *Is it possible to write `{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }` just in one place, not in all components?*

Comment: this generally happens if your router modules are imported in the wrong order;  your wildcard (404) route needs to be the *last* route in the route list, after all the other routes have been imported.

Comment: @Claies I do not declare routes in `const appRoutes: Routes = [...]`, but I declare routes in **modules**. So application routes overrides module routes. It looks like `Angular` sees `app-routing.module.ts` file for routing and then move to see to modules where there, for example, `new-cars.routing.module.ts`.

Comment: Can you add AppModule?

Comment: @yurzui I've added `app.Module.ts`

Comment: `RouterModule` is redundant in your `AppModule`. You can add it to `AppRoutingModule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is the order of your routes.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    NewsCarsModule, // this order is important
    AppRoutingModule // where you declared PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12648

Comment: so I do not need `declarations` in `@NgModule` of `app.module.ts`?

Comment: I've met strange error now: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Component PageNotFoundComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Component PageNotFoundComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

Comment: Did you add it to declarations array?

Comment: You are magic!:) But why should I add `PageNotFoundComponent` to declaraions array? I thought `PageNotFoundComponent` is just a module

Comment: Any component should be declared in some module. It's by design